# Merge Json Array to an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I have an array containing objects like

```
[
  {
   "name": "foo",
   "value": "bar"
   },
   {
    "name": "foo1",
    "value": "bar1"
   }
]
```

and I want something like

```
{"foo":"bar","foo1":"bar1"}
```

Can someone please help me out with this ?

Comment: And what is your problem?
Please look at [ask]
and [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a reduce with `Object.assign`

```js
var arr = [
  {
   "name": "foo",
   "value": "bar"
   },
   {
    "name": "foo1",
    "value": "bar1"
   }
];

var arr2 = arr.reduce((z, {name,value})=>
  Object.assign(z, {[name]: value}), {});

console.log(arr2);
```

---

Here's the ES5 version

```js
var arr = [
  {
   "name": "foo",
   "value": "bar"
   },
   {
    "name": "foo1",
    "value": "bar1"
   }
];

var arr2 = arr.reduce(function(a,b) {
  a[b.name] = b.value;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate through the array and build your object property-by-property.
It can be done easier with `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "value": "bar"
  },
  {
    "name": "foo1",
    "value": "bar1"
  }
];

var o = {};

arr.forEach(function(x) {
  o[x.name] = x.value;
});

console.log(o);
```

Comment: you can just use `console.log` in the snippets and it will display now

Comment: @naomik Oh, it looks so great now :) I haven't been at SO for a while. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's pretty new. Definitely something they've needed for a long time. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
let items = [
  {
  "name": "foo",
  "value": "bar"
  },
  {
    "name": "foo1",
    "value": "bar1"
  }
]

let myObject = {}
for (let item of items) {
  myObject[item.name] = item.value;
}

console.log(myObject);
```

Please note that this is in es6.